# VS2008 Win service deployment project don't create subfolder with xml files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-services, setup-deployment

My win service solution has 6 projects (Dlls) and one project which contain a cs file with

```
static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            new Service1() 
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

Now , I added a sub directory to this project , inside I put xml files with type content and always copy in action.

every time I compile the project and run the setup.exe it auto copy everything but does not create the new sub-folder with the files inside it. they are not created at all.

any ideas how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

In the setup project, when you add project output to the Application Folder, select "Content Files" as well as "Primary output". This will ensure that all files marked as "Content" in the source project are included in the installer.

To check that this is working, expand the setup project node in the Solution Explorer. It should have child nodes "Detected Dependencies", "Primary output from XXXX" and "Content Files from XXXX". If you right-click the content files node and select "Outputs", you will get a dialog listing all the files that will be installed, as well as their relative paths to the target directory.